# Suggest FreeWare or Paid Network Share explorer WebPart in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Can any one please suggest any good Network share explorer WebPart in SharePoint where in it provides all basic features like expand-collapse network share folders in left pane and containing files/folder in right pane, Drag and drop feature, Cut and or copy - Paste feature...

I really appreciate any help.

Nikhil.

Answer (score 2):

A Page Viewer Web Part, set to show Folders will do most of what you're asking for, the exception being the lack of a left pane.

Otherwise, you might want to check out [René Hézser's File Server Web Part](http://www.hezser.de/blog/archive/2008/03/30/access-fileserver-data-via-sharepoint.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

We've got a couple of commercial web parts which expose physical directories.

http://www.salamandersoft.co.uk/myDocuments.html

It doesn't support all of your requested functionality though such as drag and drop.

A couple of others are from Bamboo Solutions http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-file-share-library.aspx and one on CodePlex http://networkshare.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be on the SharePoint site? Why not just use Windows Explorer? Put the document library into Explorer View and you can drag/drop and cut/copy & paste from Explorer to SharePoint.

Comment: Yes it has to be in SharePoint that is the requirement.